# Is it possible to update model attributes using Ohm and Redis DB is Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redis, ohm

I'm taking a first look at Monk and the Ohm/Redis APIs and I have a simple question. Is it possible to update attributes on model objects using Ohm/Redis?

```
class Event < Ohm::Model
  attribute :name
  index :name
end

Event.create(:name => "A mistake made here...")

@event = Event.find(:id, 25)
@event.name = "I want to edit my mistake... but do not know how"
@event.save
```

Using the Ohm API I can do the following

```
require 'ohm'
Ohm.connect
Ohm.redis.set :foo, "bar"
Ohm.redis.set :foo, "bat"
```

Can't seem to find any info in the docs about how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking about, but with the following code the attribute is updated.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ohm'

Ohm.connect

class Event < Ohm::Model
  attribute :name
  index :name
end

Event.create(:name => "A mistake made here...")

@event = Event.find(:name => "A mistake made here...").first
puts @event.inspect
@event.name = "I want to edit my mistake... but do not know how"
@event.save
puts @event.inspect

@event2 = Event.find(:name => "I want to edit my mistake... but do not know how").first
puts @event2.inspect
```

I then get:

```
#<Event:1 name="A mistake made here...">
#<Event:1 name="I want to edit my mistake... but do not know how">
#<Event:1 name="I want to edit my mistake... but do not know how">
```

So the name attribute is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using a regular `#save`. Can you post more context to find out why it's not working?

```
event = Event[25]
event.name = "Updated name"
event.save
```